# ¿Cómo rotar la etiqueta del título de un eje en R?

Tags: r

Estoy trabajando con gráficos usando la función de alto nivel *plot*() y necesito que el título del eje x se muestre rotado en 180°. Para esto utilizo un vector formado por la serie de números consecutivos del 1 al 30, y otro generado a partir de una serie de valores aleatorios de una distribución uniforme. Acá se aprecian los vectores y el gráfico en cuestión:

```
X <- 1:30
Y <- runif(30)*5+1:30
plot(X,Y, xlab="eje x", ylab="eje y")
```

[image: not found]

El título del eje x, encerrado en rojo, es el que necesito rotar en 180°. El resultado esperado es tal cual se observa en la siguiente imagen, la cual realicé con un editor básico de imagen:

[image: not found]
<sub>(fuente: [subefotos.com](https://fotos.subefotos.com/8066fd09cf9d58456ebaf6e470efd103o.jpg))</sub>

He intentado con la función de bajo nivel *title*() para generar la etiqueta, pero no logro encontrar algún argumento que me permita realizar la rotación.
Si alguien conoce una forma de hacerlo utilizando otras funciones o parámetros gráficos, agradecería mucho la ayuda.

Answer (score 2):

Se puede hacer mediante un subterfugio:

Realizas la gráfica pero sin la etiqueta que quieres rotar

```
plot(X, Y, xlab="", ylab="eje y")
```

Luego añades la etiqueta con la función `text`. El argumento `srt` te permite rotar del modo que necesitas.

```
text(x=15, y=-5, labels="ejex x", srt=180, xpd=TRUE)
```

[image: Gráfico con la etiqueta rotada]